# pygame not reaching K_a input or any input from input in my class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a class that allows users to make text boxes for pygame games. I'm able to reach the `mousebuttondown` command but it doesn't reach that keyboard input statement. Given below is my whole code along with that part that is giving me an issue. I also need a way to take the input for every letter.

**not printing reached**

```
def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                if event.type == pygame.K_a:
                    print("reached")
                    self.dict_text[id] = []
                    self.dict_text[id].append("a")
                    self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{str(self.dict_text[id])}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                      (self.x, self.y))
                else:
                    print("didn't")

            else:
                pass
```

**whole code - ignore update**

```
import pygame

pygame.font.init()


class textBox:
    def __init__(self, surface, id, color, width, height, x, y, antialias, maxtextlen):
        self.surface = surface
        self.id = id
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.maxtextlen = maxtextlen

        self.text_list = []
        self.text_list_keys = []
        self.currentId = 0
        self.click_check = False
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
        self.dict_all = {}

        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        # for i in self.text_list_keys:
        #     if self.id not in i:
        #         self.text_list_keys.append(self.id)
        #         self.text_list.append(tuple(self.id))
        #     else:
        #         self.nothing()
        self.dict_all[self.id] = tuple((self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        self.dict_text = {}

    def update(self, events, mousepos):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and ((self.x + self.width) > mousepos[0] > self.x) \
                    and ((self.y + self.height) > mousepos[1] > self.y):
                print("reached: " + mousepos)
                self.click_check = True
            else:
                self.click_check = False

            if self.click_check:
                print("1")
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    print("@")
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        print("reached")
                        new_t = ""
                        for j in range(len(self.text_list)):
                            t = (self.text_list[j][0]).index(self.getId(self.currentId))
                            new_t = t
                        self.text_list[new_t].append("a")
                        self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{self.text_list[new_t]}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                          (self.x, self.y))

                    else:
                        print("this")

            else:
                pass

    def rect(self, text_id, mousepos):
        x, y, width, height = self.dict_all[text_id]
        if ((x + width) > mousepos[0] > x) and ((y + height) > mousepos[1] > y):
            print("yes")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getId(self, text_id):
        self.currentId = text_id

    def nothing(self):
        return False

    def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                    if event.type == pygame.K_a:
                        print("reached")
                        self.dict_text[id] = []
                        self.dict_text[id].append("a")
                        self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{str(self.dict_text[id])}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                          (self.x, self.y))
                    else:
                        print("didn't")

                else:
                    pass
```

**test.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame_textbox import textBox

pygame.init()

win_width = 500
win_height = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("test")

run = True
while run:
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    a = textBox(screen, 1, (255,  255, 255), 100, 30, 100, 100, True, 20)
    # a.getId(1)
    a.rect(1, mouse)
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    a.main(events, mouse_pos, 1)
    pygame.display.update()
```

**edited main**

```
def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    # keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    # if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                    if event.type == pygame.K_a:
                        print("reached")
                        self.dict_text[id] = []
                        self.dict_text[id].append("a")
                        self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{str(self.dict_text[id])}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                          (self.x, self.y))
                    else:
                        print("didn't")

            else:
                pass
```

---

Updated files

```
import pygame

pygame.font.init()


class textBox:
    def __init__(self, surface, id, color, width, height, x, y, antialias, maxtextlen):
        self.surface = surface
        self.id = id
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.maxtextlen = maxtextlen

        self.text_list = []
        self.text_list_keys = []
        self.currentId = 0
        self.click_check = False
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
        self.dict_all = {}
        self.pressed = False
        self.dict_text = {}
        self.dict_text[id] = []

        # pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        # for i in self.text_list_keys:
        #     if self.id not in i:
        #         self.text_list_keys.append(self.id)
        #         self.text_list.append(tuple(self.id))
        #     else:
        #         self.nothing()
        self.dict_all[self.id] = tuple((self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        self.dict_text = {}

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    # def update(self, events, mousepos):
    #     for event in events:
    #         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    #             exit()
    #         if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and ((self.x + self.width) > mousepos[0] > self.x) \
    #                 and ((self.y + self.height) > mousepos[1] > self.y):
    #             print("reached: ", mousepos)
    #             self.click_check = True
    #         else:
    #             self.click_check = False
    #
    #         if self.click_check:
    #             print("1")
    #             if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    #                 print("@")
    #                 if event.key == pygame.K_a:
    #                     print("reached")
    #                     new_t = ""
    #                     for j in range(len(self.text_list)):
    #                         t = (self.text_list[j][0]).index(self.getId(self.currentId))
    #                         new_t = t
    #                     self.text_list[new_t].append("a")
    #                     self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{self.text_list[new_t]}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
    #                                       (self.x, self.y))
    #
    #                 else:
    #                     print("this")
    #
    #         else:
    #             pass

    def rect(self, text_id, mousepos):
        x, y, width, height = self.dict_all[text_id]
        if ((x + width) > mousepos[0] > x) and ((y + height) > mousepos[1] > y):
            print("yes")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getId(self, text_id):
        self.currentId = text_id

    def nothing(self):
        return False

    def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.pressed = False
                if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                    self.pressed = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        if self.pressed:
                            print("reached")
                            self.dict_text[id].append("a")
                            self.surface.blit(
                                self.font.render(f'{str(self.dict_text[id])}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                (self.x, self.y))
                        else:
                            print("didn't")

                else:
                    pass
```

**test.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame_textbox import textBox

pygame.init()

win_width = 500
win_height = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("test")

run = True
a = textBox(screen, 1, (255, 255, 255), 100, 30, 100, 100, True, 20)

while run:
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    events = pygame.event.get()
    a.draw()
    a.getId(1)
    a.rect(1, mouse)
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    a.main(events, mouse_pos, 1)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()


    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is stored in the `key` attribute of the event, rather than the `type` attribute:
(see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html))

<s>`if event.type == pygame.K_a:`</s>

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_a:
```

Any way, that won't solve your issue, because the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event doesn't evaluate and key state and even has no `key` attribute. Only the `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` events provide a key.

You have to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate if an additional key is hold down when the mouse button is pressed:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if self.rect(id, mousepos):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            print("reached")
            # [...]
```

---

If you want to detect when the mouse is on the button and <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed, then you've to use the `KEYDOWN` event:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if self.rect(id, mousepos):
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            print("reached")
            # [...]
```

---

If you want to detect if the button was pressed by the mouse and later you want to detect if <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed, then you have to store the state if the button is pressed:

```py
class textBox:
    def __init__(self, surface, id, color, width, height, x, y, antialias, maxtextlen):
        # [...]
        self.pressed = False

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        for id in self.dict_text:
            self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{str(self.dict_text[id])}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)), (self.x, self.y))

    # [...]

    def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.pressed = False
                if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                    self.pressed = True
            
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if self.pressed:
                        print("reached")
                        
                        self.dict_text[id] = []
                        self.dict_text[id].append("a")
                        self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{str(self.dict_text[id])}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                            (self.x, self.y))
                    else:
                        print("didn't")
```

Of course you've to instance the button (`a`) before the main application loop:

```py
a = textBox(screen, 1, (255,  255, 255), 100, 30, 100, 100, True, 20)

run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    a.draw()
    a.rect(1, mouse)

    # [...]
```

---

Complete code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.font.init()


class textBox:
    def __init__(self, surface, id, color, width, height, x, y, antialias, maxtextlen):
        self.surface = surface
        self.id = id
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.maxtextlen = maxtextlen

        self.text_list = []
        self.text_list_keys = []
        self.currentId = 0
        self.click_check = False
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
        self.dict_all = {}
     # for i in self.text_list_keys:
        #     if self.id not in i:
        #         self.text_list_keys.append(self.id)
        #         self.text_list.append(tuple(self.id))
        #     else:
        #         self.nothing()
        self.dict_all[self.id] = tuple((self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        self.dict_text = {}
        self.pressed = False

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        for id in self.dict_text:
            self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{str(self.dict_text[id])}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)), (self.x, self.y))
       

    def update(self, events, mousepos):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and ((self.x + self.width) > mousepos[0] > self.x) \
                    and ((self.y + self.height) > mousepos[1] > self.y):
                print("reached: " + mousepos)
                self.click_check = True
            else:
                self.click_check = False

            if self.click_check:
                print("1")
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    print("@")
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        print("reached")
                        new_t = ""
                        for j in range(len(self.text_list)):
                            t = (self.text_list[j][0]).index(self.getId(self.currentId))
                            new_t = t
                        self.text_list[new_t].append("a")
                        self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{self.text_list[new_t]}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                          (self.x, self.y))

                    else:
                        print("this")

            else:
                pass

    def rect(self, text_id, mousepos):
        x, y, width, height = self.dict_all[text_id]
        if ((x + width) > mousepos[0] > x) and ((y + height) > mousepos[1] > y):
            print("yes")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getId(self, text_id):
        self.currentId = text_id

    def nothing(self):
        return False

    def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.pressed = False
                if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                    self.pressed = True
            
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if self.pressed:
                        print("reached")
                        
                        self.dict_text[id] = []
                        self.dict_text[id].append("a")
                    else:
                        print("didn't")
```

```py
pygame.init()

win_width = 500
win_height = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("test")

a = textBox(screen, 1, (255,  255, 255), 100, 30, 100, 100, True, 20)

run = True
while run:
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    # a.getId(1)
    a.draw()
    a.rect(1, mouse)
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    a.main(events, mouse_pos, 1)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: It is still not reaching.

Comment: @rishi Of course it is you have to press _A_ and then the press the mouse button. Or did I misunderstand your question? Do you want to _reach_ it when the mouse is on the rectangle and only the button is pressed?

Comment: @rishi I've extended the answer.

Comment: So the sequence of event is require is as follows - first I click the textbox to activate it, then I'm able to press a letter on my keyboard and is stored in a list which is categorized by the id number of the textbox (inside a dictionary). After all this the text is blitted onto the screen. Thank you

Comment: I have added an updated main, but that too doesn't seem to be working. self.rect check whether the textbox has been clicked so it has to come before checking for keydown.

Comment: @risi The mouse has to be on the rectangle and at the same time _A_ has to be pressed. It has to be at the same time! There is no state in your program that states, that the button has been clicked bfore.

Comment: I was actually testing that out with ```update``` but it didn't work. ```self.click_check``` was supposed to check whether the button was clicked or not, in fact that part was working but the rest of the code wasn't.

Comment: @rishi The button has to be instanced before the main application loop. If the button is continuously recreated in the loop then the state is lost. Again I've extended the answer.

Comment: It is still not printing reached.

Comment: @rishi No, it works. I've tested it. Press the button with the mouse (once). Then press _A_. I've add the complete code to the answer.

Comment: Thank you it is printing reached now, but I'm still wondering why it isn't blitting a onto to textbox

Comment: @risi You've to draw the text in draw. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, there are still many flaws in the code, I'm able to print 'a' in the textbox but only one letter is able to fit. I'll try to figure out the problems or ask for help in a different question. Just an update for your answer, you can iterate through dict_text[id] and blit that font otherwise it shows ['a']. Thank you so much again.